Integrate vault system in laravel application managed by docker
I am trying to integrate the vault system to manage the env credential. Earlier I was managing the credentials using heml-chart.  After vault integration application sometimes throws db refused to connect error.
I am creating .env in Dockerfile and update the .env inside service-entry.sh
Env file is getting generated correctly which I am verifying using cat .env command inside service-entry.sh.
Any suggestion would be helpful in why the application is throwing db refused to connect error in some requests.
Here is my Dockerfile
FROM php:7.3-fpm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /b2b

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y \
   wget \
   build-essential \
   libpng-dev \
   libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
   libfreetype6-dev \
   locales \
   zip \
   libzip-dev \
   jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
   vim \
   unzip \
   curl \
   libxml2-dev \
   openssl \
   procps \
   jq

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl soap
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY service-entry.sh .

COPY ./aqualens_b2b_in .

# Create .env file and set permissions
RUN touch .env && chmod 0777 .env

RUN chmod -R 0777 ./storage
RUN chmod -R 0777 ./bootstrap

RUN mkdir -p ./storage/framework/cache
RUN mkdir -p ./storage/framework/sessions
RUN mkdir -p ./storage/framework/views

RUN chmod -R 0777 ./storage

# Set the entry point for the container
CMD ["sh","/b2b/service-entry.sh" ]

RUN composer install
RUN php artisan optimize

Here is service-entry.sh file
#!/bin/sh

# For VAULT

: ${VAULT_ENABLED:="true"}
: ${VAULT_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_TOKEN_FILE:="/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token"}
: ${VAULT_URI:="http://vault-cluster-url.local:2000"}
: ${VAULT_ROLE:="vault-myapp-config-b2b-auth-role"}
: ${VAULT_BACKEND:="company/myapp/myapp-config"}
: ${VAULT_DEFAULT_CONTEXT:="myapp-b2b"}

# Check and print the current directory and its permissions
echo "Current directory: $(pwd)"
ls -ld .
ls -a
ls -l

if [ "$VAULT_ENABLED" = "true" ]; then
    kubernetesToken=$(cat "${VAULT_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_TOKEN_FILE}")
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Error: Unable to read Kubernetes service account token file"
    fi

    vaultEndpoint="${VAULT_URI}/v1/auth/kubernetes/login"
    H1_KUBE="Content-Type: application/json"
    H2_KUBE="Authorization: Bearer ${kubernetesToken}"

    requestData="{\"role\":\"${VAULT_ROLE}\",\"jwt\":\"${kubernetesToken}\"}"
    response=$(curl -s -X POST -H "$H1_KUBE" -H "$H2_KUBE" --data "${requestData}" "${vaultEndpoint}")


    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Error: Unable to authenticate with Vault"
    fi

    access_token=$(echo "${response}" | jq -r .auth.client_token)
    if [ -z "$access_token" ] || [ "$access_token" = "null" ]; then
        echo "Error: Unable to retrieve access token from Vault response"
    fi

    H1_VAULT="X-Vault-Token: ${access_token}"
    H2_VAULT="Accept: application/json"

    RESPONSE_VAULT=$(curl -s -H "$H1_VAULT" -H "$H2_VAULT" "${VAULT_URI}/v1/${VAULT_BACKEND}/${VAULT_DEFAULT_CONTEXT}")

    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Error: Unable to fetch vault data"
    fi

    export_statements=$(echo "$RESPONSE_VAULT" | jq -r '.data | to_entries[] | @sh "export \(.key)=\(.value)"')
    if [ -z "$export_statements" ]; then
        echo "Error: No data retrieved from Vault"
    fi

    echo "Logging Qualens Vault Integration:"
    echo "export_statements"
    echo "$export_statements"

    # Read each export statement and process it
    echo "$export_statements" | while IFS= read -r line; do
        eval "$line"
        key=$(echo "$line" | cut -d'=' -f1 | cut -d' ' -f2)
        value=$(echo "$line" | cut -d'=' -f2- | sed "s/^'//" | sed "s/'$//")
        if grep -q "^${key}=" .env; then
            # Update existing variable
            sed -i "s|^${key}=.*|${key}=${value}|g" .env
        else
            # Add new variable
            echo "${key}=${value}" >> .env
        fi
    done

     # Debug: Print contents of .env file after update
    echo "Contents of .env file after update:"
    cat .env

fi

# For PHP
php-fpm


What is the actual error message?  What specific line or command is producing it?  I'm a little surprised to see chmod 0777, which disables normal security controls, and a Vault setup appear at the same time; is it possible Vault is refusing to run because key directories are world-writable?  Can you use the vault CLI tool over manual HTTP calls?

Hi @DavidMaze Issue is when i try to server any request from the app it works which means vault keys are getting added to .env file. Issue in most of the routes or API request app throws db connect refused error.

Regarding chmod 0777 I will take care of this later
